# Avoid automatic work item linking when pushing to git repositories

Tags: git, svn, tfs, tfs-2015

Is it possible to avoid the automatic work item linking in tfs 2015 when psuhing to git repositories?

Problem:  we have to import svn repos with svn commit messages including hashtags for another issue tracker system.  when pushing these imported git-repos to tfs, tfs scans all the commit messages for hashtags and does automatic work item linking to "matching" tfs work items
--> we don't want tfs to do this for this push

How to configure this behaviour?

Comment: Are you using # in the git commit message? For eaxmple, If you use # in your git commit message as in git commit -m'fixes #123' TFS will automatically add the commit as a linked item in workitem specified.

Comment: yes i know, but these "#" are buried in the svn commit messages and we want to import the whole svn commit history

Answer (score 0):

Afraid there is no way to forbidden the automatically association. This is by designed.

You may have to manually delete the redundant work items for this push.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the case for TFS 2015 but in Azure DevOps there is a setting on the repository for automatically creating links for work items mentioned in a commit comment that you can turn off.

Details are provided in the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/repository-settings?view=azure-devops

There may be a similar setting in TFS 2015?

This is what it looks like in Azure DevOps

[image]